# How to round a decimal to a specific accuracy

Tags: matlab

So I am given a vector f_1sided:

```
f_2sided = linspace(-5e11,5e11,958576); 
f_1sided = f_2sided(end/2+1:end);
```

I want to find the index of the entry of f_1sided == 11.07e9.

Problem: f_1sided has many entries which are roughly 1.107e10, but not exact. I want to find the most exact one. For example, entry 106110 is 110695042119,813. The next entry is 110696085335,002.

I am thinking about a way to round the entries of f_1sided. But when I round the two entries that I mentioned, for example, I don't want both to be 11.07e9, but only the one which is more exact..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you’re looking for the entry that is closest to a given one:

```
desired = 11.07e9;
distances_to_desired = (f_1sided - desired).^2;
[~, closest_index] = min(distances_to_desired);
```

Here, of course, `desired` is the number in `f_1sided` that you’re looking for, `distances_to_desired` contains for each value in `f_1sided` its (squared) distance to `desired`, and `closest_index` is the index into `f_1sided` such that the distance is smallest.

Comment: why the square? `abs()` seems a better fit. The square feels like an unfinished attempt of an euclidean distance

Comment: @AnderBiguri They’re equivalent, so it’s a matter of taste. Also, `abs` may require a branch making it slower. Taking `sqrt` to have the 2-norm is slower, as well.

Comment: thank you so much, Lumen! - just one question: what is the `~ `supposed to do ?

Comment: @Luk You’re welcome! The tilde `~` ignores the first return argument of `min`. That would be the minimum distance found. If you want to have that value, replace `~` by `minimum_distance_found`, or whatever you prefer. If `minimum_distance_found == 0`, then the *exact* value `desired` was found.

Comment: @Lumen yes, yes they are, but it masks a bit the information about the actual distance. To be fair, with this huge array, it may be better to be faster as you propose

Comment: Just a small note. Maybe you want to check with `find(min_dist == distances_to_desired)` if the closest value exists multiple times. It depends of you data if this is possible and if you need to care about it.